# How to check Already existing data in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check that if classection=Six:B already exist in firebase database then it show toast message please guide  I am trying to solve this from 3 days but I cannot solve it Here is my code it doesnot show any error or toast

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
Query query = ref.child("Students");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String  classsection=""+dataSnapshot.child("classsection").getValue();
        if(classsection.equals("Six:B"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MaintabclasActivity.this, "Class Six B is Already Exist", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
           // updateclasfiveb();

        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(MaintabclasActivity.this, "error", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to check if `Six:B` exists for a particular student ID or is it if any student has that value is stored in the database you display a toast?

Comment: yes If any student has this valve then it show toast

Answer (score 0):

A query in Firebase consists of two parts:

1. A call to order the child nodes of a path on its key, or a certain property.
2. A call to then filter the child nodes down by a certain value or range.

In your case:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Students");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("classsection").equalTo("Six:B");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(MaintabclasActivity.this, "Class Six B is Already Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(MaintabclasActivity.this, "error",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: E/FastThread: did not receive expected priority boost

Comment: That seems unrelated to the  code in my answer. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hey @JameelAhmad Did you make any progress on this? As said, that error message seems unrelated to the original problem and to the code in my answer. But if you're still having problems, please edit your question to show what you've tried with the code from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addListenerForSingleValueEvent ,use onCompleteListener to get data once  if you really wants access real time database. because addListenerForSingleValueEvent is for cache data.

```
//  If you have child node id to go through each node use below method.
    
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        
        
        ref.child("Students").child("node_id_under_student").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
                }
            }
        });
```

// Or use query method with ValueEventListener  to listen for changes in database.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Students");
Query databaseQuery= ref.orderByChild("classsection").equalTo("Six:B");
    
    
   databaseQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           
         String  classsection=""+dataSnapshot.child("classsection").getValue();
        if(classsection.equals("Six:B"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MaintabclasActivity.this, "Class Six B is Already Exist", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
           // updateclasfiveb();

        }}
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```